# Ways of Implementing a GUI in Swing, Multithreading is a Concern

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

The goal is a GUI where in a window, having the play button pressed will release the GUI resources and start to run my game (the game is done outside of Swing, in LWJGL).

This is the first way I can see myself doing it. To me the safer option looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     // setup gui objects
     JFrame frame = ...;
     frame.setVisible(true);
     // wait for the play button to be pressed
     synchronized(frame) { 
         frame.wait(); 
     }
     // free the gui objects, start the game
     frame.dispose();
     startGame();
}
// by the way, this method is called from the button's action listener
public void onPlayButtonPress(JFrame parent) {
    // end the UI   
    synchronized(parent) {     
       parent.notify();
    }
}
```

The reason this seems 'safe' to me is that the cleanup for the GUI and the game execution is done inside the main thread. Here is the second way I can see myself doing it, but I'm not sure how I feel about it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     // setup gui objects
     JFrame frame = ...;
     frame.setVisible(true);
}
public void onPlayButtonPress(JFrame parent) {
    // free the gui objects
    parent.dispose();
    startGameInNewThread();
}
```

This second way of doing it seems more preferrable in that it is simpler, but I am worried of some problems coming up. For example:

- Disposing the frame in the Event Dispatch Thread could mess things up?
- Starting a new thread for the game while the main thread has already terminated?

So the reason I'm asking this question is because I'm looking for the best way to implement this, but I'm also kind of curious if and why any wierd things will happen if I implement my program the second way.

Comment: Instead of disposing of the frame, you could simply hide it.  If that's not an option, you could start the game thread first (so that there is a non-daemon thread running) and then dispose of the frame.  I prefer the second option personally